# jenkins error after update java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /var/lib/jenkins/users/admin

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

Hi I've made an jenkins update on my debian mashine.

Now I got this error after the update:

> java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /var/lib/jenkins/users/admin
>     at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:498)  at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)    at
>   hudson.model.UserIdMigrator.migrateUsers(UserIdMigrator.java:97)  at
>   hudson.model.UserIdMapper.load(UserIdMapper.java:184)     at
>   hudson.model.UserIdMapper.init(UserIdMapper.java:75) Caused:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104) Caused:
>   java.lang.Error   at
>   hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)    at
>   hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
>     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)   at
>   jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1096)    at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)  at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused:
>   org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException     at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)    at
>   jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:48)  at
>   jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1130)   at
>   jenkins.model.Jenkins.(Jenkins.java:932)    at
>   hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:85)    at
>   hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:81)    at
>   hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233) Caused:
>   hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad    at
>   hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparrently this is an error in an older version of Jenkins, try updating jenkins:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21330

edit: In the ticket are some comments describing how renaming the last successful job folder fixed it for them.

Comment: Its not an issue in job folder. already tried this. error is in this folder: `/var/lib/jenkins/users/admin`

Comment: I tried to upgrade directly from 141 to 171 ... does not work. upgrade from 141 to 151 works fine. but all later versions throws this error

Comment: version 153 is the latest I can use all newer ones have this error

Comment: Is java 11 required since version 154?